# MDT Deployment Failure during unattend.xml

Tags: deployment, pxe-boot, wds, mdt-2013

I am attempting to deploy Windows 10 Education on a number of machines using WDS(for PXE) and MDT2013 Update 2 installed on Windows Server 2012 R2.

The setup is failing right after the install os step, when dism is applying unattend.xml

The error message is Failure(5627): -2147467259 0x80004005

Anyone can help with this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your unattended partitioning is not correct;
see here

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95650bde-e9b0-4b76-9d10-502d7456435d/failure-5627-193-run-dismexe?forum=mdt

Comment: This does not seem to be it. My partitions are configured well for windows 10. The failure is happening as soon as dism.exe /Image:C:\ /Apply-Unattend runs. What is the LTIApply responsible for?

Comment: LTIApply.wsf => Apply image (OS or PE) to the hard drive. https://github.com/monosoul/MS-Deployment-toolkit-scripts/blob/master/Scripts/LTIApply.wsf

Comment: I attempted to remove any custom partitions so the machine was left with the windows 10 default ones. (500MB for System and the rest for OS) I still experienced the same error.